# CMFCMenuButton with a programmatically constructed menu?

Tags: c++, menu, mfc, cmfcmenubutton

I'm new to the `CMFCMenuButton` control; here's my code in `OnInitDialog()`:

```
// Load application list into menu button
m_ApplicationMenu = CreateMenu();   
m_MenuInfoSize = 2;
m_MenuInfo = new MENUITEMINFO[m_MenuInfoSize];
memset(m_MenuInfo, 0, sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) * m_MenuInfoSize);
UINT menuIndex = 0;
BOOL b; 
// 1st menu item
memset(m_MenuInfo + menuIndex, 0, sizeof(MENUITEMINFO));
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_DATA;
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].wID = menuIndex;
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].dwTypeData = new WCHAR[10]; 
swprintf_s(m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].dwTypeData, 10, L"%s", L"A1");
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].cch = wcslen(m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].dwTypeData) + 1;
b = InsertMenuItem(m_ApplicationMenu, menuIndex, TRUE, &(m_MenuInfo[menuIndex]));
menuIndex++;
// 2nd menu item
memset(&m_MenuInfo[menuIndex], 0, sizeof(MENUITEMINFO));
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_DATA;
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].wID = menuIndex;
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].dwTypeData = new WCHAR[10]; 
swprintf_s(m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].dwTypeData, 10, L"%s", L"B2");
m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].cch = wcslen(m_MenuInfo[menuIndex].dwTypeData) + 1;
b = InsertMenuItem(m_ApplicationMenu, menuIndex, TRUE,  &(m_MenuInfo[menuIndex]));
menuIndex++;
// Attach menu to CMFCMenuButton
m_ApplicationList.m_bOSMenu = TRUE;
m_ApplicationList.m_bRightArrow = FALSE;
m_ApplicationList.m_bStayPressed = TRUE;
m_ApplicationList.m_bDefaultClick = FALSE;
m_ApplicationList.m_hMenu = m_ApplicationMenu;
    // Testing the constructed menu with the dialog's menu bar
::SetMenu(this->m_hWnd, m_ApplicationMenu);
```

When I ran the application, the `CMFCMenuButton` displayed a dropdown menu when I clicked on it... but those two items were empty, no text and no image.

I added the last line to test my constructed menu; and the two items showed up in the menu bar properly.

I also tried using a menu created from the resource editor. It showed up fine in menu bar, but in the `CMFCMenuButton`, there were again empty spaces.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
m_ApplicationMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
```

Also, you'd better use `1` as the first `menuIndex` if you want to get the `m_nMenuResult` of `CMFCMenuButton` in click event. Because:

> `CMFCMenuButton::m_nMenuResult`
>
> An integer that indicates which item the user selects from the pop-up menu.
>
> The value of this member variable is zero if the user cancels the menu
> without making a selection or if an error occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I did wrong, CreateMenu() vs CreatePopupMenu() [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/30/46594.aspx]. Your comment about menu index is also correct; my menu's first item, using index 0, wasn't triggering the event.